# maws2.0.py yield start ^SyntaxError: 'yield' outside function

Tags: python, python-3.x

The program maws.py was developed by students in 2015 at Uni-Heidelberg but I could not contact the developer. I checked maws.py with PyCharm and the many indentation problems were solved, I hope. However, running maws.py (program has 1615 lines,  so only a few lines are shown):

```
def gen_range(lower, upper, step):
    start = lower
while start < upper:
    yield start
    start += step
```

etc...

I get the following error:

```
 yield start
    ^
SyntaxError: 'yield' outside function

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I do not know how to solve this as I am a python user and know almost nothing about programming.

Comment: That indentation is not correct, so I linked you a question that explains how indentation works in Python and how to fix problems like this. That said, why were there "many indentation problems" in the first place? I can't imagine it was published like that. Maybe the file got corrupted somehow.

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/igemsoftware/Heidelberg_15/blob/master/MAWS.py) (found by googling), that function looks ok. Maybe you need to re-download it.

Comment: @Johnny Exactly what I was going to say. [Here's the direct link to the function](https://github.com/igemsoftware/Heidelberg_15/blob/master/MAWS.py#L27-L31) btw. Although, the number of lines doesn't match -- OP says 1615 but GH says 1218.